# Testing click event with Konacha/Poltergeist (and Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, poltergeist, konacha

I have Konacha running with the Poltergeist driver in my `config/initializers/konacha.rb` file. I've made sure that I set `config.driver :poltergeist` in that file.

I'm having trouble getting Poltergeist to interact with the page. My test (`toggler_spec.js`) is pretty simple:

```
describe 'Trip detail toggler', ->
  describe 'clicking a show link', ->
    it 'shows the trip description', ->
      $('body').html(JST['templates/one_index_trip'])
      $('.detail_toggle').click()
      assert.isFalse $('.detail').hasClass 'hidden'
```

The template:

```
<div class="trip_links">
  <a href="/trips/1" class="detail_toggle">Show Details</a>
  <p class="detail hidden">This text should be hidden.</p>
</div>
```

And here's `toggler.js.coffee`

```
$('.detail_toggle').click ->
  $(this).siblings('detail').removeClass 'hidden'
```

I've simplified it as much as possible.

Through logging, etc., I know that it's including the right files and everything, but Poltergeist won't click. I also tried `$('.detail_toggle').trigger('click')` in my test, and that didn't work either. Thanks for any ideas you have.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to take a screenshot? May be it will help to see what happened. https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#taking-screenshots-with-some-extensions